# How to find the surface integral on the lateral surface $S_3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

If $\vec{F}=4x \hat{i}-2y^{2}\hat{j}+z^{2}\hat{k}$ taken over the region bounded by the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=4$, $z=0$ and $z=3$. To verify Divergence theorem, I have doubt to find the surface integral on the lateral surface $S_3$ ...

Solved in [Regarding verifying Gauss-Divergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397757/regarding-verifying-gauss-divergence-theorem)

[image]

Doubt:

On $S_3$, $\hat n=(xi+yj)/2$, $F.\hat n=2x^2-y^3=8\cos^2\theta-\sin^3\theta$

What is $dS?$

Taking projection on $xz$ plane
$$dS=\frac{dxdz}{|n.j|}=\frac{2}{y}dxdz=\frac{2d\theta dz}{\sin\theta}$$

Then $$\iint_{S_3}\vec{F}.\hat n\,dS=\int_{z=0}^3\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{(2(2\cos(\theta))^{2}-(2\sin(\theta)^{3})2d\theta dz}{\sin\theta}$$

It is not matching with  [Regarding verifying Gauss-Divergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397757/regarding-verifying-gauss-divergence-theorem)

Means, my calculation is not right. What is happening here? Why they are considering $$dS=2d\theta dz$$...Please write in full...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=2\cos\theta$ then $dx=-2\sin\theta d\theta$. Also, $|n\cdot j|=|\sin\theta|$. So $$dS=\frac{2|\sin\theta|d\theta dz}{|\sin\theta|}=2d\theta dz$$

The alternative approach, the area element $dS$ is equal to the length element along the base, multiplied with the height element
$$dS=dl dz$$
For the length element, use polar coordinates $$dl=rd\theta=2d\theta$$